MS SQL Server always encryption using secure enclaves integration with JDBC
I am trying to connect to encrypted data base using JDBC and have the following configurations
I have an encrypted column(name) on a table(student) using the randomized encryption and able to get the decrypted data using the following query using SSMS
DECLARE @name nvarchar(200) = 'stack%'; 
SELECT name, subject FROM student WHERE name LIKE @name;

The above script to get executed, I have enabled Always Encryption and Enable Secure Enclaves and Enclave Attestation Protocol as None

Also added Column Encryption Setting = Enabled

I am using JDBC application to connect to the encrypted database
Connection string: jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;databaseName=database;SelectMethod=cursor;columnEncryptionSetting=Enabled;enclaveAttestationUrl=null;enclaveAttestationProtocol=NONE

below is the code to get the data
        
        String sql = "DECLARE @name char(200) = ? ; "
                    + "SELECT name FROM Student WHERE name LIKE @name;";
        DatabaseManager db = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        List list = new ArrayList();
        try {
            db = getDatabaseManager();
            conn = db.getConnection();
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setBytes(1, "stack%".getBytes());
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("CustomerName"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (db != null) {
                db.close();
                db = null;
            }
        }

But when running the application, I am unable to get the data and encountering the below exception

Operand type clash: varchar(5) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_DB', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'database') collation_name = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' is incompatible with nvarchar(200) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_DB', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'Database')

Update on the issue:
I was able to resolve the above issue but encountering other issue using JDBC though did refresh the metadata in SQL Server.
Please find the issue below
Incorrect encryption metadata was received from the client. The error occurred during the invocation of the batch and therefore the client can refresh the encryption metadata by calling sp_describe_parameter_encryption and retry.
The following is the syntax I used to refresh the metadata
exec sys.sp_refresh_parameter_encryption  @name =  'dbo.GetPersonData_1'
Please help if there is some information required or gap

You misunderstand how this encryption thing works. The query must be parametrized on the "outside", but you pass the whole query to SQL Server, where it no longer has access to the encryption keys.
You need to use: PreparedStatement and send the @name variable as parameter (which is what SSMS is doing behind the scenes). Your java code need to be able to access the keys/enclaves. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-always-encrypted-with-secure-enclaves-with-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver16

Hi, thanks for the response. But using PreparedSatement, I am encountering  Operand type clash: varbinary(5) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_DB', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'db') is incompatible with char(200) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_DB', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'db') collation_name = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'

You should edit your code in the question, this is whole different issue

I mean, you should add the whole code that uses preparedstament :) Now you only added the error, it's no help to anyone.

Thanks again. I did edit and update the code and error as well

Setbytes is wrong, use setString

No luck. Already tries this approach, but getting "Incorrect encryption metadata was received from the client. The error occurred during the invocation of the batch and therefore the client can refresh the encryption metadata by calling sp_describe_parameter_encryption and retry."

Sounds like you're using wrong driver or some other issue. Just follow the Microsoft examples. You should also disable sendStringAsunicode or whatever the setting is called

Using sqljdbc42.jar and sendStringAsunicode is disabled. Any resolution will be greatly helpful and appreciated.

Uhh, you have to use like 10.2 at least. 4.2 is so old it probably has its own wikipage by now

Did you manage to make it work? @RatnaSrikanth

No @Sigemannen. I have changed the version to10.2. Though the metadata got refreshed, the Java application is throwing Incorrect encryption metadata was received from the client. The error occurred during the invocation of the batch and therefore the client can refresh the encryption metadata by calling sp_describe_parameter_encryption and retry.

If you're using secure enclaves in an environment where attestation services aren't available, the value of this keyword should be NONE. Requires JDBC 12.2 or later. You should really read that link and go through the process so you meet the requirements.

Also: This feature requires the RSASSA-PSA signature algorithm. This algorithm was added in JDK 11, but not back-ported to JDK 8. Users who wish to use this feature with the JDK 8 version of the Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server must either load their own provider, which supports the RSASSA-PSA signature algorithm, or include the BouncyCastleProvider optional dependency. The dependency will be removed at a later date if JDK 8 back ports the signature algorithm or if the support lifecycle of JDK 8 ends

Hi, tried this with Java 11 as well. No luck, still throwing the same

And what about with absolutely latest and greatest ms jdbc driver

using 10.2, I believe it is the latest and suitable version

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc doubt it's the latest
